# How to show two the system has an infinite number of solution

Tags: linear-algebra

For the system of equations: $3x–6y+12z=–9$, $2x–4y+8z=–6$,Without solving the equation, give the reason why the system has an infinite number of solution?

Comment: Cause they're the same equation modulo a multiplicative factor.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply equation (1) by $\frac{2}{3}$ and you will get the same equation as of plane (2). So both are the equation of same plane. Hence have infinte solutions.

Comment: @lolololok, do this answer looks acceptable to you ? If yes then accept it by tapping on the tick button just below upvote and downvote button